# Accessing value from ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

Note: I'm a beginner to Swift and MapKit so bear with me please. I appreciate it.
I have a SwiftUI view that takes an ObservableObject as input

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: PostRowViewModel
```

And within that ObservableObject there is a @Published field:

```
@Published var post: Post
```

Now what I want to do is to display a map of using the lat and long values that are fields in this post object. Now the Map view in MapKit is as follows:

```
            Map(coordinateRegion: Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>)
```

So I need to provide it with a binding of the region of the post I'm trying to display. What I tried to do is to initialize the region as follows:

```
@State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: viewModel.post.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: viewModel.post.location.coordinate.latitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))
```

Using the info from the viewModel. However I get this error:

Cannot use instance member 'viewModel' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.

So I searched online and found that to solve the issue you need to use an init function however since the viewModel is given as input to the view and I have Environment variable I dont want to include an init function. I've also tried to create a function inside the viewModel that returns a Binding as follows:

```swift
   func createMapRegion() -> Binding<MKCoordinateRegion> {
        @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: post.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: post.location.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))
        return $region
    }
```

But I get the warning:
Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.
Because the state is being accessing outside since when I then create the map I do it like so:

```
            Map(coordinateRegion: viewModel.createMapRegion())
```

So I'm not sure how I can access this info from the post published object using the viewModel and create a Map when the viewModel is given as input to the view.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Code:

ViewModel:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

@MainActor
@dynamicMemberLookup
class PostRowViewModel: ObservableObject, StateManager {
..
 
    @Published var post: Post

..
    init(post: Post...) {
        self.post = post
        ...
    }
    
    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<Post, T>) -> T {
        post[keyPath: keyPath]
    }
}
```

View:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct PostRowView: View {
.
.
.            
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PostRowViewModel
    

.
.

    
        
    var body: some View {
       // I want to create a map here that uses the post stored in the viewModel. 
       Map(coordinateRegion: ...)
}


}
        

    
}
```

Where I want to access the values for lat and long using the Post struct which is:

```swift
struct Post: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
    .
    .
    .
    var location: LocationInfo
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Where LocationInfo is:

```swift
struct LocationInfo: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var countryCode: String
    var coordinate:  Coordinate
    var id = UUID()
}
```

And coordinate is:

```swift
struct Coordinate: Codable, Hashable {
    let latitude, longitude: Double
}
```

Comment: The path of least resistance is probably to make `region` a `@Published` value on your view model.

Comment: So if I create a Published value what do I assign it to since if I assign it as so:     @Published var postRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: post.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: post.location.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02)) I will get the same error which is Cannot use instance member 'post' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Also Map takes a Binding as input so how can I get a Binding from a Published property

Comment: I suggest you create a [mre] so that someone can provide an answer that applies directly to your code

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I appreciate it. I edited the post and I hope its now more clear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the path of least resistance is probably to put `region` in a `@Published` variable on your `ObservableObject`:

```
class PostRowViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var post: Post
    @Published var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    init(post: Post) {
        self.post = post
        self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: post.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: post.location.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))
    }
}

struct PostRowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PostRowViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region)
    }
}
```

---

Note that you don't actually need a view model for this. You could also do something like:

```
struct PostRowView: View {
    var post: Post
    @State private var region : MKCoordinateRegion = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
            .onAppear {
                region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: post.location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: post.location.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I wanted! Thanks you so much!